# Handler Thread: Only one Looper may be created per thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to use `Handler` and `HandlerThread` from foreground service to execute task on new thread. But when I call `HandlerThread.run()` I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread`

I am starting the thread using this code:

```
networkThread = new HandlerThread("Network Thread");
    if(networkThread.getLooper() == null)
        networkThread.run();

handler = new Handler(networkThread.getLooper());
handler.postDelayed(updateTask, 1000);
```

Comment: Need a bit more code to be able to tell, but also, you want to call `networkThread.start()`, not `networkThread.run()`. And you don't need the conditional; `getLooper()` will always be null if the thread hasn't started yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android each `Thread` has only one `Looper`, when you use `HandlerThread`, it creates a `Looper` when you start the handler thread.

`HandlerThread` is just a java `Thread` which has a `Looper`.

**Root cause:** Your code is not correct.

**Solution:** Change your code

From

```
networkThread = new HandlerThread("Network Thread");
    if(networkThread.getLooper() == null)
        networkThread.run();

handler = new Handler(networkThread.getLooper());
handler.postDelayed(updateTask, 1000);
```

To

```
// Create and start a handler thread.
networkThread = new HandlerThread("Network Thread");
networkThread.start(); 

handler = new Handler(networkThread.getLooper()); // The calling thread must wait until a Looper has been created in the handler thread.

// Post your task to handler thread to process
handler.postDelayed(updateTask, 1000);
```